# Require presence of ENV VAR on Rails app start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, configuration, environment-variables

Gems such as [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) and services such as [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) allow run time Rails app configuration using *environmental variables*.

How can I validate the presence of an *env var* is required for the app, and fail to start if it is not present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could put something like this into an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/check_env.rb
fail "MY_ENV not defined" unless ENV["MY_VAR"]
```